# Blender Cache Error. 0 frames in memory Cache is Outdated

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, baking, hair, cache

[image]

[image]

Hi, so for the last couple of days i've been trying to bake hair particles from a tree I modeled  but I keep getting this error that says "0 frames in memory (0 B), cache is outdated!" and I can't find an answer for this.

At first I thought that maybe I did something wrong with the project file, but then I started a new one with the default cube, I added some hair particles and the same error still appeared. Does anyone know how to fix this? Or what is the cause?

Comment: I just found out. You can't bake while in Edit Mode. Hope this helps future straglers:)

Answer (score 2):

I had this "0 frames in memory, cache is outdated". My collection was empty. after I clicked RigidBodyWorld. Bake works:)[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching too, what I did is I clicked on remove rigid body world and afterwards I put it back and everything worked! I had different simulations in the same project and I think blender couldn't handle it or I messed up in the bakes I don't know! But let me know if this works for you!